# Configurable Map Viewer Advanced Search Widget

Tags: arcgis-server, configurable-map-viewer, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I add Advanced Search Widget on my configurable map viewer application, I have also configure proxy file and paste Attributes Tables, the problem is that search by attributes, by adresse works but search by spatial don't. where is the problem ? I am using WFS layers.

Comment: What errors are you getting in the Developer Tools? I suspect it will be a configuration issue.